# How to configure Serilog to send email with message body in html format?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I am using Serilog in my project based on dotnet core 3.1 and using its Email sink to send emails using Serilog. The version of serilog for email is :

```
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Email" Version="2.3.0"/>
```

I want to send email body to be in Html format. How to do it ? I have configured serilog to send mails through appsettings.json file in the below way :

```
{
  "Name" : "Email",
  "Args" : 
  {
     "fromEmail" : "<emailId>",
     "toEmail" : "<emailId>",
     "enableSsl" : false,
     "mailSubject" : "<Mail Subject>",
     "isBodyHtml" : false,
     "mailServer" : <mailServer>,
     "smtpPort" : <port>,
     "outputTemplate" : "Error occured at - {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}\nError Message :{Message:lj} ",
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel" : "Error"
  }

}
```

So according to above configuration, if error is logged using Serilog , a mail will be sent as well.
Below is the code for logging Error level-

```
  _logger.LogError(ex,$"Directory address is {address}");
```

I want to show this address as hyperlink. How to do it? Setting **isBodyHtml to true**  doesnot help.
After setting **isBodyHtml** to true, i change the error message in the this format :

```
 _logger.LogError(ex,$"Directory address is <a>{address}</a>");
```

But this does not help.

Comment: Well, `<a>{address}</a>` is not a valid hyperlink, so that's not going to work. `<a href="{address}">{address}</a>` might work

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto : This does not work. The message is coming as "Directory address is <a href='C:\\Address'>C:\\Address</a>"

Comment: Because that's obviously not a valid web URL. You might be able to get it to work with `<a href="file:\\{address}">{address}</a>`, but I wouldn't count on it

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto : That does not work too. The mail body looks like : Address is <a href='file:\C:\TestFolder'>C:\TestFolder</a>.                                                                     Serilog doesnot convert the text to Hrml and print it as it is.                                           Also isBodyHtml given in the settings in my question is not of any use , i think.